# How to I make my object stay still after it levitates up/down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

people of stack overflow. I am trying to make a drone game for my personal project and I need some help. I want to make a drone game, but I am stuck at a certain bit. Being that I am unable to make a drone stay in the same position after it levitates up or down. After I press the selected button for levitation the object simply either keeps going up or keeps going down. I was wondering if somehow I would be able to keep the drone in the same Y position after I bring it up or down to a certain point. Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time and have a good day!!

Code ->

```
public class Levitating : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody ourDrone;

private void Awake()
{
    ourDrone = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    MovementUpDown();

    ourDrone.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * upForce);
}

public float upForce;

void MovementUpDown()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        upForce = 15;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        upForce = -3;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could set some height limits, and set the drone's speed to 0 once they're reached. Or you could toggle the rigidBody's isKinematic as well.

```
float upperLimit = 10;
float lowerLimit = -10;

void MovementUpDown()
{
    if (transform.position.y >= upperLimit || transform.position.y < lowerLimit)
    {
        ourDrone.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        ourDrone.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    if (transform.position.y < upperLimit && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        upForce = 15;
    }
    else if (transform.position.y > lowerLimit && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        upForce = -3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it keeps going in the same direction is that the **upForce** is never resetted when the user stops pressing the up/down keys.

A "real-world" approach would be to make the default velocity of the drone a Vector3 with the same value as the gravity force.
This makes the drone levitating.

You can put this logic right after the Input check

```
// Make the drone default velocity the same value of the gravity acceleration, with opposite direction
private const Vector3 DRONE_DEFAULT_VELOCITY = new Vector3(0, 9.81f, 0);

public float upForce;

private void Update()
{
    MovementUpDown();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{    
    ourDrone.AddRelativeForce(DRONE_DEFAULT_VELOCITY * upForce);
}

void MovementUpDown()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        upForce = 15;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        upForce = -3;
    }
    else
    {
        // Resetting the force muultiplier
        upForce = 1
    }
}
```

As I did in the example above, it's also suggested to put the Input check logic into Update() method, and the physical logic into FixedUpdateMethod().

The Update() method is called each frame, while the FixedUpdateMethod() is called only for objects physical update.